# Python unittest cannot access local environment variables in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

This one really is stumping me. When I set an API key as an environment variable and then try to run a test with unittest that uses this API key, the test cannot access the API key. I don't want to set the environment variable in the test itself because the value is secret and I don't want it to be accidentally tracked by my VCS.

```
$ export API_KEY=hunter2
$ python -m unittest discover tests

    ERROR: setUpClass (tests_system.TestInit)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/travis/build/jamesbrunet/callhub-python-wrapper/callhub/auth.py", line 23, in __init__

    self.api_key = os.environ["API_KEY"]

  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.6/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__

    raise KeyError(key) from None

KeyError: 'API_KEY'
```

The interesting thing is that if I just run a single test file with `python test-file.py` it executes successfully and can access the API key. I only get this issue if I use `python -m unittest discover <directory of test file>`. Unfortunately, I need to use the latter command to discover all the test files in the directory.

The docs for unittest don't reference environment variables so I'm a bit at a loss to what's going on here.

Edit: I did some additional testing on my local machine and the scope of this issue seems limited to running these commands in PyCharm and Travis. Both of those use virtual environments. Perhaps this is related to @AndrewAllaire's comment on this post?

Comment: Well I can see why it won't work, when the tests are discovered they are launched in a sub process that is not in your bash environment. How to fix it is a different matter. Maybe have a hidden file off the home directory that stores it and have a function that reads the value from that file.

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue, but it works fine for me (using Python 3.6.9 on WSL). The remark from @AndrewAllaire might be right specifically in your case, but it doesn't look like the tests are spawned in subprocesses that do not see the environment. Besides, I think that forked processes always inherit env variables.

Comment: @joelhoro surprised it worked for you. Perhaps my explanation was wrong--but not sure what else it could be in his case.

Comment: Thanks for that @joelhoro. I tried reproducing this under a bunch of different circumstances and this issue only seems to be happening in PyCharm and Travis CI, which both are using virtual environments. In PyCharm and Travis, unittest discover <dir> is causing this problem while unittest <full_path_to_file> works fine. How interesting, its almost like unittest discover is messing around with the virtual environment?

Comment: Just tried using a virtual environment, still works fine.

Comment: Very strange. Do you have any advice on how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet resolved this mystery with `unittest discover`, but in case you are a wary future traveller from google and a knight in shining armour did not appear to save the day, this janky workaround will do the trick:

```
python -m unittest tests.file_1
python -m unittest tests.file_2
python -m unittest tests.file_n
```

If using coveralls to monitor your test coverage, you can execute your tests like this and they will execute properly and show your combined code coverage:

```
  coverage run --parallel-mode --source=sourcedir -m unittest tests.file_1
  coverage run --parallel-mode --source=sourcedir -m unittest tests.file_2
  coverage run --parallel-mode --source=sourcedir -m unittest tests.file_n
  coverage combine
```

This isn't great, so I've got my fingers crossed we'll get a solution from someone who has more experience with python-unittest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure the reason why this happens. However the solution is to add the `-s` flag to the `unittest discover` command and your test folder.

From the unittest `--help` command:

```
  -s START, --start-directory START
                        Directory to start discovery ('.' default)
```

So make sure your start folder is the `tests` directory, and it should work.

Final command
`python -m unittest discover -s <test-dir>` where test-dir is your where your tests are.

Now all my environmental variables were picked up correctly.